# Auto-login on tty if usb key is available

Tags: linux, autologin

I'm using Gentoo Linux with Openrc and [CDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CDM). I want to perform automatic login on tty1 if usb key is inserted. E.g. I can check hash-sum of some files on this usb drive to be sure that it's correct key. All answers that I've found were related to Systemd configuration. Is it possible to auto-login without using Systemd?

Comment: This could be a bit more tricky for USB devices may not always be mounted at the same position in the file system (storage devices normally at `/dev/sd{a..z}[1..]`, e. g., which normally depends on the order of mounting or plugging in USB sticks).

Comment: @Nepumuk I know device UUID, I think I can use it to mount this key